# JS Function only works once

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a page that allows conversions of temperatures from Celsius to Fahrenheit or vice-versa.
The user enters a start temperature, a finish temperature, and which way to convert.

The page currently works, but only once? (What I mean by this is; the first time the conversion results will be printed correctly in a table. If the user re-enters data and submits the form, it just shows the headers of the table, no results.)

This is my first time using JS, so it may be something very obvious.

Would appreciate any help!

P.S. I would love advice on my etiquette, but remember I'm a JS noob so be nice! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>

        function myFunc() {
            start = document.getElementById("start").value;
            finish = document.getElementById("finish").value;
            conv = document.getElementById("conv").value;
            conversionTable("conversion", conv, start, finish);
            return false;

        }

        function conversionTable(tagID, convType, from, to) {
            conv = document.getElementById(tagID);

            table = document.createElement("TABLE");
            head = table.createTHead();
            trh = head.insertRow(0);
            if (convType == 'c2f') {
                headCel = trh.insertCell();
                headCel.innerHTML = "<b>Celsius</b>";
                headCel = trh.insertCell();
                headCel.innerHTML = "<b>Fahrenheit</b>";
            }
            else  {
                headCel = trh.insertCell();
                headCel.innerHTML = "<b>Fahrenheit</b>";
                headCel = trh.insertCell();
                headCel.innerHTML = "<b>Celsius</b>";
            }

            conv.replaceWith(table);

            for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
                tr = table.insertRow();
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    tr.setAttribute("class", "even");
                } else {
                    tr.setAttribute("class", "odd");
                }
                td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
                td = tr.insertCell();
                if (convType == 'c2f') {
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c2f(i)));
                }
                if (convType == 'f2c'){
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(f2c(i)));
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function c2f(c) {
            let result = c * 9 / 5 + 32;
            result = (result.toFixed(1));
            return result.toString()
        }

        function f2c(f) {
            let result = ((f - 32) * (5 / 9));
            result = result.toFixed(1);
            return result.toString()
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label>Start:</label><input type="text" id="start">
    <br><label>Finish:</label><input type="text" id="finish">
    <br><select id="conv">
        <option value="c2f">Celsius to Fahrenheit</option>
        <option value="f2c">Fahrenheit to Celsius</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" onclick="myFunc();return false;">
</form>
<div id="conversion"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so many global variables. use `var, let, or const`

Comment: Because you replace the element that you reference and the replacement does not have the id.

Comment: You could also use a button (of type="button") rather than a submit button to avoid concerns about the form being submitted (and code executing once because the page is submitted).

Comment: Etiquette: Try to name your functions descriptively for easier reading and refactoring in the future. `myFunc` is not a very helpful name for a function. Keep up the good work ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing conv with the table. On second run, the program is not able to find `conv`, that is the reason for your error. Use the below code instead

```
conv.innerHTML="";
            conv.append(table);
```

```js
function myFunc() {
            start = document.getElementById("start").value;
            finish = document.getElementById("finish").value;
            conv = document.getElementById("conv").value;
            conversionTable("conversion", conv, start, finish);
           

        }

        function conversionTable(tagID, convType, from, to) {
            conv = document.getElementById(tagID);

            table = document.createElement("TABLE");
            head = table.createTHead();
            trh = head.insertRow(0);
            if (convType == 'c2f') {
                headCel = trh.insertCell();
                headCel.innerHTML = "<b>Celsius</b>";
                headCel = trh.insertCell();
                headCel.innerHTML = "<b>Fahrenheit</b>";
            }
            else  {
                headCel = trh.insertCell();
                headCel.innerHTML = "<b>Fahrenheit</b>";
                headCel = trh.insertCell();
                headCel.innerHTML = "<b>Celsius</b>";
            }
conv.innerHTML="";
            conv.append(table);

            for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
                tr = table.insertRow();
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    tr.setAttribute("class", "even");
                } else {
                    tr.setAttribute("class", "odd");
                }
                td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
                td = tr.insertCell();
                if (convType == 'c2f') {
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c2f(i)));
                }
                if (convType == 'f2c'){
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(f2c(i)));
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function c2f(c) {
            let result = c * 9 / 5 + 32;
            result = (result.toFixed(1));
            return result.toString()
        }

        function f2c(f) {
            let result = ((f - 32) * (5 / 9));
            result = result.toFixed(1);
            return result.toString()
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Test</title>
   
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label>Start:</label><input type="text" id="start">
    <br><label>Finish:</label><input type="text" id="finish">
    <br><select id="conv">
        <option value="c2f">Celsius to Fahrenheit</option>
        <option value="f2c">Fahrenheit to Celsius</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunc()">
</form>
<div id="conversion"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. Only issue is, I am now having another problem :/  The conversions don't work with numbers greater than 99?

Comment: Hmm, when I try the conversion 32 to 100, fahrenheit to celsius, the table just shows the headers